# Unlocker howto?! doesn't do anything

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, context-menu, shell-extensions

in an answer to a [previous question](https://superuser.com/questions/223852/windows-vista-7-need-permissions-to-delete) another user recommended a tool to me, `Unlocker`. Its original homepage is offline, but there are plenty of websites which offer version 1.9.0 which I downloaded from 2 places, compared the filesize, it was identical, and installed it, then rebooted, but it does not do anything except that there's a new icon in the tray.

There are no new menu items in the Windows Explorer's context menu nor does anything happen when I send any element to Unlocker using the "send-to" menu. It created two shortcuts in the start menu, "Start Unlocker" and "Start Unlocker Assistant" which also both don't do anything. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should get it off the creator's page instead.

http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/#download

1.9.2, for both 32 and 64 bit windows. you'll want to click the "Download Unlocker 1.9.2 - 32 and 64 bit version" link.

be sure to use advanced during installation and disable the delta toolbar that's bundled with it. you don't want that.

Comment: The above link generates a message that it is blocked because it has been reported to contain unwanted software.

Comment: @fixer1234 Indeed it does. - "Several optional and usually unwanted software programs may be offered during the installation process. This can only be avoided by being careful not to click on the 'next' or 'install' buttons (...)" (see [here](http://deletedwikipedia.gawker-labs.com/wiki/Unlocker)). **I recommend downloading the portable version** from [Softpedia](http://www.softpedia.com/get/PORTABLE-SOFTWARE/System/File-management/Unlocker-Portable.shtml)

Answer (score 11):

Do you have 64-bit version of Windows 7 ? Unlocker doesn't work on 64-bit OS, get [LockHunter](http://lockhunter.com/)

Comment: Thanks. I found a 64-bit version of Unlocker and it works!

Answer (score 4):

Actually there is a 64 bit version of Unlocker, look for a file such as: Unlocker1.9.1-x64.exe  This program works great in Windows 7 64-bit, but not all download sites have the 64 bit version of Unlocker available.  Have Fun being in control of your computer!

Answer (score 2):

As Matteius said, searched "Unlocker1.9.1-x64.exe" and found this (after a few redundant results):

http://files.brothersoft.com/internet/miscellaneous/Unlocker1.9.1-x64.exe

This works for me on Win7 64bit.

Comment: Did you check and scan this link? I generally don't trust BrotherSoft links.

Comment: Scanned with _Microsoft Windows Security Essentials_, and nothing found.

Comment: [Download the portable version from Softpedia](http://www.softpedia.com/get/PORTABLE-SOFTWARE/System/File-management/Unlocker-Portable.shtml) instead. Comes with both versions in a 111KB .zip file.

Answer (score 0):

I Uninstalled it, and install it by enabling the "Explorer extension" checkbox during installation. It works well for me.

Comment: not for me... I check the box, but no unlocker in context menu !!??